# In the MCU, were any characters or entities powerful enough to resist The Snap?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

Based on canonical sources, is there any evidence to confirm that there were characters or entities in the MCU that were powerful enough that they managed to simply resist the effects of the Snap?

As in, they would have been Snapped, but were able to defend against it?

This does not seem to have been discussed within the movies themselves, but other canonical sources may include details.

Comment: Not that we saw. If we didn't see it, it didn't happen.

Comment: Due to the randomness of the snapping, and the fact that this hasn't been shown and probably won't be shown again means u'll probably won't ever get an answer.

Comment: Then surely the answer would be that there are no known instances of this in canon?

Comment: This may be better asked in [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) since it's scope is broader than just movies and TV.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We know that the Eternals were able to survive the snap. This, however, is not due to 'power': the Eternals were created before the Infinity Stones were, thus making them 'immortal' to the Infinity Stones' power.

Comment: Accepted as an answer on the grounds that there was "something" about them that stopped them from being snapped.

Comment: @AaarghZombies If anything, it was them being technically not *alive*.

Comment: Robots don't get snapped?

Comment: @AaarghZombies Living things were the target.

Comment: I meant biological life, Presumably Vision and Ultron wouldn't be snapped either, or the Anti-Monitor's robot army?

Comment: @AaarghZombies true, but they had already been killed **before** the snap...

Comment: Oh, and this answer is just wrong. Infinity Stones were primordial, existing before anyone created anything. And even if it wasn't the case, I don't see a reason why precedence would matter.

Comment: Agreed, this is wrong because the Snap only targeted living beings and the Eternals are robots. It had nothing to do with their "power" at all.